# How can I add a delay on MouseEnter Event without activating other buttons

Tags: java

I am newbie in java and doesn't have much idea about programming. I am trying to build a GUI to control a Robotic arm. My goal is when the mouse will enter on a button a command will be sent and I achieved that.

Now I am trying to add a delay on mouse entering, I used this given below code

```
private void jButton3MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    sendCommand(Constants.reverseCommand);
    try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    }
    sendCommand(Constants.forwardCommand);
    jButton3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
```

as I have multiple buttons so whenever I move my mouse for the destination button, the other buttons are activated and first they perform the delay and then the destination. How can I overcome this problem? Any kind of example code will be appreciated.

Comment: Yours smells like an XY Problem where you could be using a completely wrong approach. Your best bet is to tell us more of the details of what overall goal that you're trying to achieve, and less on how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: My goal is I want to set a delay on mouseEntering as I have multiple buttons so while crossing the other buttons they are activating. I need to send the command of the destination button without activating them while crossing.